# How to pass sh command inside withCredentials for maven in Jenkins file

Tags: shell, jenkins

I'm always getting the not found error in the 6th line(Dsonar.branch.name) of the code from my Jenkinsfile below. If I swap the 6th line as Dsonar.sources it says the source is not found.

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'sonar_token', variable: 'token')]) {
sh"""
mvn sonar:sonar \
-Dsonar.projectKey=app \
-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.test.dev \
-Dsonar.login="917336a835asdf3528c863498"\
-Dsonar.exclusions=$env.WORKSPACE/apps/core-app/src/test
-Dsonar.branch.name=$env.BRANCH_NAME
-Dsonar.sources=$env.WORKSPACE/apps/
-Dsonar.exclusions=$env.WORKSPACE/registry/apps/support-app/src/test
-Dsonar.exclusions=src/apitest/**,src/test/**
"""
}

    
Error below,
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:13 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-18T07:15:59Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ -Dsonar.branch.name=feature/docker-build
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/nt-registry_feature_docker-build@tmp/durable-d9e51887/script.sh: 3: -Dsonar.branch.name=feature/docker-build: not found
```

Comment: The backslash at the end of the first four lines indicate that the command continues on the next line. On the fifth line you have no backslash so it will always think the next line is a new command. Make sure you add a backslash on each line of your `mvn` command except the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the function below instead sh command. It works as expected.

sonarResult = sonarqubeScan(
serverName: 'sonarqube',
sonarScannerExec: "$env.WORKSPACE/sonar-scanner-4.0.0.1744-linux/bin/sonar-scanner",
credentialsId: 'sonar_token',
sources: ".",
addlArgs: config.sonar.sonarAdditionalArguments
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).